# ¿Como evaluar un: ' " ' en un String?

Tags: java, java-8

Sonara un poco confuso pero pasa esto: Estoy haciendo un programa en java que me diga que tipo de carácter es el que se esta procesando en base a una cadena. Dichos elementos pueden ser caracteres o una cadena de los mismos, depende como lo dictamine mi recortador / divisor de la cadena. Por ejemplo:

public static void main ( ) { }

En donde "public" refiere a una parte de la cadena denominada como palabra reservada, "static" también, "void" también, "main" a un nombre, "(" a un corchete izquierdo, ")" a un corchete derecho [....].

Al yo evaluar esas subcadenas, lo hago en un switch, en donde la subcadena la guardo en una variable auxiliar. De esta forma esta el switch:

```
switch (enCuestion) {
                    case "while":
                        objTabla.insertar_TS(String.valueOf(posicion+1), enCuestion, "Palabra reservada");
                        break;
                        
                    case "funcion":
                        objTabla.insertar_TS(String.valueOf(posicion+1), enCuestion, "Palabra reservada");
                        break;
                        
                    case "for":
                        objTabla.insertar_TS(String.valueOf(posicion+1), enCuestion, "Palabra reservada");
                        break;
                        
                    case "switch":
                        objTabla.insertar_TS(String.valueOf(posicion+1), enCuestion, "Palabra reservada");
                        break;
                        
                    case "do":
                        objTabla.insertar_TS(String.valueOf(posicion+1), enCuestion, "Palabra reservada");
                        break;
                        
                    case "(":
                        objTabla.insertar_TS(String.valueOf(posicion+1), enCuestion, "LParent");
                        break;
                        
                    case ")":
                        objTabla.insertar_TS(String.valueOf(posicion+1), enCuestion, "RParent");
                        break;
}
```

Todo normal con esos ejemplos, pero aquí viene el detalle, que pasa si en algún momento, quiero comparar con un  ' " ' (Comillas dobles)? sabiendo que en el case del switch, y por ser string debo de poner ' "" ' encerrando entre las comillas dobles al caso a evaluar.

Si yo pongo:

```
case """: //<- aqui esta la doble comilla siendo evaluada
******
break;
```

Me dice que esta mal y que hay un error. Entiendo que es por que ellos son "delimitadores" de string y por ende piensa que inicia otro string en seguida.
He leido que se puede hacer con string crudo o similar (Creo que incluso es interpolar el string).
Como se hace en dart o en kotlin, estilo:

```
"${"}"
```

Como puedo hacer para evaluar ahí las comillas dobles?.

Comment: Debes escaparla `"\""`. La diagonal inversa le indica que lo trate como un carácter literal. Igual con char puedes hacer eso `'\''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes escapar la doble comilla `"\""` , de esta forma detectaría el carácter sin problema:

```
...
 case "\"":
...
```